bootstrap: как изменить class кнопки через медиазапрос в CSS
При просмотре страницы на десктопе , используются вот такой класс крупных кнопок:
class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
Хочу, чтобы при просмотре страницы на мобилке, кнопки становились меньше и использовался такой класс:
class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
Можно ли это сделать через медиазапрос в CSS?

Попробуйте добавить оба класса.
